# How to create a file from a template if it does not exist or open existing copy?

Tags: find-file, insert, template

Trying to make a function that I can call to create a file from a template or open an existing file. Current attempt is as follows:

```
(defun journal-entry ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((daily-name (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d)"))
        (journal-path "~/Dropbox (Personal)/journal/"))
    (find-file (concat journal-path daily-name ".md"))
    (insert "JOURNAL" "\n" daily-name)))
```

Problem with this is that every time I call it. The `( insert )` content gets re added

Comment: How about using something like?  `(if (file-exists-p name-of-file) do-x do-y)`  The function in the question has no conditions, so you'll need to familiarize yourself with this like `if` and `cond`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this version of the function:

```lisp
(defun journal-entry ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((daily-name (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d)"))
     (journal-path "~/Dropbox (Personal)/journal/")
     (journal-file (concat journal-path daily-name ".md")))
     (find-file journal-file)
     (unless (file-exists-p journal-file)
         (insert "JOURNAL" "\n" daily-name))))
```

`Unless` like `if not`, so if the file isn't exist (checked in `(file-exists-p journal-file)`), the `(insert "JOURNAL" "\n" daily-name)` will be executed.

I've added creating `journal-file` because it used in the script twice.